# Keeping changes same in merging branches in

Tags: git, merge, version-control, git-merge

I have been using Git for a while and I know basics of merging, tho I have one confusion on how others maintain the code changes after merging?

I have `master` branch, and `feature_a` branch which is created from `master`. There are some changes in `master` branch and as well as `feature_a` branch, to get latest changes in `master` I merged `feature_a` into `master` branch.

So now `master` has all the latest changes, and now i want to continue in `feature_a` branch to add more changes, but the thing is `feature_a` does not have changes of `master` branch which are made after branch out and before merge, which is bothering me from continuing on `feature_a` branch.

Am I missing any concept or is there any way to keep both branches on same level after merging? Should I merge `master` in to `feature_a` after merging `feature_a` into `master` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but the thing is feature_a does not have changes of master branch which are made after branch out and before merge, which is bothering me from continuing on feature_a branch.

Then all you need to do is *rebase* the new part of `feature_a` on top of master:

```
git switch feature_a
git rebase --onto master A feature_a
```

You would go from

```
m--m--M--m (master)
     /
 a--A--a--a (feature_a)
```

To

```
m--m--M--m  (master)
     /    \
 a--a      --a'--a' (feature_a)
```

Comment: Ok so after each merge (feature_a into master) I need to rebase feature_a on master, after that i can continue on feature_a for next change and do the same thing when i again need to merge it, is that correct ?

Comment: @Darshan That is the general idea, yes. I do the rebase only of the part from `feature_a` which is not yet merged into `master`.

Comment: What do you mean by "rebase only of the part from 'feature_a' which is not yet merged" ? Do i need to skip the merge part?

Comment: @Darshan That is what the `rebase --onto` does in my answer: rebase everything after `A`: `A` is the last commit from `feature_A` being merged to `master`.